# Converting a string into a function that is not in a namespace in clojure

Tags: clojure

Here is the sample code I want to get to work:

```
(letfn [(CONC [f] f)
        (CONT [f] (str "\newline" f))]
((voodoo "CONC") "hamster"))
```

Is there some voodo that will make it call the CONC function with hamster as the parameter?  That is, is there some way to convert the string "CONC" into a function that is not bound to a namespace but rather to a local binding?

EDIT:

To be clearer, the way this will be called is:

```
(map #((voodoo (:tag %)) (:value %)) 
    [ 
        {:tag "CONC" :value "hamster"} 
        {:tag "CONT" :value "gerbil"}
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd probably solve this by creating a map of functions indexed by strings:

```
(def voodoo 
  {"CONC" (fn [f] f)
   "CONT" (fn [f] (str "\newline" f))})
```

Then your desired code should work directly (exploiting the fact that a map is a function that looks up it's argument)

```
(map #((voodoo (:tag %)) (:value %)) 
    [ 
        {:tag "CONC" :value "hamster"} 
        {:tag "CONT" :value "gerbil"}
    ]
)
```

Note that the functions here are fully anonymous - you don't need them to be referenced anywhere in the namespace for this to work. In my view this is a good thing, because unless you also need the functions somewhere else then it's best to avoid polluting your top-level namespace too much.

Comment: +1 -- my answer is only concerned with how to implement `voodoo`, but this is definitely the more sensible solution in most contexts.

Comment: This is probably the best answer with the [evalive](https://github.com/fogus/evalive) project also being an interesting answer to the question of accessing functions that are not bound in a namespace

Answer (score 4):

No. Eval does not have access to the local/lexical environment, ever.

Edit: This is not a very good answer, and not really accurate either. You could write voodoo as a macro, and then it doesn't need runtime access to the lexical environment, just compile-time. However, this means it would only work if you know at compile time that the function you want to call is `x`, and so it wouldn't be very useful - why not just type `x` instead of `(voodoo "x")`?

```
(defmacro voodoo [fname]
  (symbol fname))

(letfn [(x [y] (inc y))]
  ((voodoo "x") 2))
;; 3

(letfn [(x [y] (inc y))]
  (let [f "x"]
    ((voodoo f) 2)))
;; error
```

Comment: Actually a truly black voodoo which would work is possible, if you're evil enough to use it -- see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504171/converting-a-string-into-a-fuction-that-is-not-in-a-namespace-in-clojure/7514238#7514238) and Fogus's [evalive](https://github.com/fogus/evalive). :-)

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's sort of possible:

```
(defmacro voodoo [s]
  (let [env (zipmap (map (partial list 'quote) (keys &env))
                    (keys &env))]
    `(if-let [v# (~env (symbol ~s))]
       v#
       (throw (RuntimeException. "no such local")))))
```

...and now we can do weird stuff like this:

```
user> (defn example [s]
        (letfn [(foo [x] {:foo x})
                (bar [x] {:bar x})]
          ((voodoo s) :quux)))
#'user/example
user> (example "foo")
{:foo :quux}
user> (example "bar")
{:bar :quux}
user> (example "quux")
; Evaluation aborted.
user> *e
#<RuntimeException java.lang.RuntimeException: no such local>
```

That "Evaluation aborted" means an exception was thrown.

You could also replace the `throw` branch of the `if` in `voodoo` with `(resolve (symbol ~s))` to defer to the globals if no local is found:

```
(defmacro voodoo [s]
  (let [env (zipmap (map (partial list 'quote) (keys &env))
                    (keys &env))]
    `(if-let [v# (~env (symbol ~s))]
       v#
       (resolve (symbol ~s)))))
```

...and now this works with definition of `example` as above (though note that if you are experimenting at the REPL, you will need to recompile `example` after redefining `voodoo`):

```
user> (defn quux [x] {:quux x})
#'user/quux
user> (example "quux")
{:quux :quux}
```

Now, this is an abuse of Clojure's facilities which one would do well to try to do without. If one cannot, one should probably turn to [evalive](https://github.com/fogus/evalive) by Michael Fogus; it's a library which provides an "eval-with-locals" facility in the form of an `evil` function and a couple of utilities. The functionality seems to be well factored too, e.g. something like the `~(zipmap ...)` thing above is encapsulated as a macro and `evil` there appears to be almost a drop-in replacement for `eval` (add the env parameter and you're good to go). I haven't read the source properly, but I probably will now, looks like fun. :-)

Comment: (Tested with Clojure 1.3-RC0.)

Answer (score 2):

Im not really clear what you are asking for so i'll try a couple answers:

if you have a string that is the name of the function you wish to call:

```
 (def name "+")
 ((find-var (symbol (str *ns* "/" name))) 1 2 3)
```

this would give voodoo a deffinition like this:

```
(defn voodoo [name args] (apply (find-var (symbol (str *ns* "/" name))) args))
#'clojure.core/voodoo
clojure.core=> (voodoo "+" [1 2 3])
6
```

clojure.core=> 
this assumes your function is in the current namepace `ns`.

if you want to turn a string into a function you could use this pattern

```
(let [f (eval (read-string "(fn [] 4)"))] (f))
```